# Hiding Cells Containing

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, formatting, conditional-statements

I'm looking to hide certain cells when they contain "No Requirement", after researching online all I can find is how to hide a whole row or column, not just three or four cells on the whole sheet. Is this even possible?

I was thinking maybe an if statement, but I'm not even sure if that is possible.

I don't have any code because I don't even know how to start.

Comment: As you see, there are several ways to make individual cell's content invisible. I personally always use it in following ranking: 1. Formula to show either result or "" (easy to find and understand for later readers) 2. Number format ;;; (errors visible, little effort) 3. Conditional formatting (higher effort, risk of unwanted splitting into more and more conditions) 4. Font Color like background color (errors not visible)

Answer (score 2):

Say we want to "hide" a cell, but not hide the entire row or entire column.  We can "hide" the cells **contents** by setting the color of the font equal to the color of the cell's background In this way:

1. the cell will appear "empty in the sheet
2. the cell's content will be visible in the Formula Bar
3. the content can easily be edited

**EDIT#1:**

This coloration can be implemented with **Conditional Formatting** with the FormulaIs option:

```
=AND(NOT(ISERROR(E2)),E2="No Requirement")
```

[image]

*(the error check is redundant in this case)*

Comment: That's a good idea. Conditional formatting could be used to accomplish this on a large scale, if need be.

Comment: Conditional formatting would mean that setting the condition `="No Requirement"` would only execute for cells with "No Requirement", meaning errors _and any other value not equal to "No Requirement"_ would also show. It is a good idea.

Comment: @Asger  THANK YOU! See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: @TateGarringer See my **EDIT#1:**

Comment: @Asger  Your suggestion is FANTASTIC.  I intend to use it in the future to make error values `Bold` and `Red`  **Thanks again!**

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide individual cells, only entire columns, rows and worksheets.

Comment: An if() statement of the form : =IF(A1="No requirement","",A1) will put the contents of cell A1 unless it contains "No requirement"...

Answer (score 1):

You can give the cells a custom number format of ;;; (three semicolons) to make their values "invisible".

By this, only error values are shown, but you can still use the cell's values within other formulas. This is not good style, as other persons may accidentially delete the cell's values, but it's better than to give it e. g. white color on white background, **as errors are still shown**.

`Range.NumberFormat = ";;;"`